# Can you create rules in Gmail?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

In MS Outlook, you can create rules so different kinds of mail can go in different folders.  Can you do the same thing in Gmail, so all your emails from a list go in a specific subfolder instead of your general inbox?

Comment: Note: Gmail uses labels, not folders. The nice thing is that a message can have multiple labels, and the inbox is just another label. This allows you to organize your conversations, yet keep important ones on the front page/inbox.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes. See the note on point 4 below.

> Gmail's filters allow you to manage the flow of incoming messages. Using filters, you can automatically label, archive, delete, star, or forward your mail, even keep it out of Spam.
>
> **To create a filter**
>
> 1. Click the down arrow in your search box. A window that allows you to specify your search criteria will appear.
> 2. Enter your search criteria. If you want to check that your search worked correctly, click the search button.
> 3. Click **Create filter with this search** at the bottom of the search window. If you need to verify the search results, you can click the x to collapse the filter options. Clicking the down arrow again will bring the window back with the same search criteria you entered.
> 4. Choose the action(s) you want the filter to take.
>      
>      To keep organized, many people like to have incoming messages automatically labeled and removed from their inbox until they can look at them later at a more convenient time. If you want to do this, make sure to select **Skip the Inbox (Archive it)** and **Apply the label:** when you create your filter.
> 5. Click the **Create filter** button.

Also,

> **To use a particular message to create a filter**
>
> 1. Select the message in your message list.
> 2. Click the **More** button, then **Filter messages like these**.
> 3. Enter your filter criteria in the appropriate field(s).

From the Gmail [help page on using filters](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=6579).

Answer (score -1):

Yes, first create label in settings and then you have to create filter.

select the mails and send that mails to that label.

http://www.tomjepson.co.uk/how-to-auto-forward-specific-emails-in-gmail/

This will surely work for you.

Comment: Please include the actual instructions here and use the link purely as a reference.