# I get too much Spam

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, spam-prevention

In the last 3 or 4 months I have been receiving a huge amount of Spam.  Most of it goes directly to bin, and then I have to report it as Spam. I also get a few that go straight to inbox.  Everyday I am moving Spam from the bin into the Spam folder.  I sometimes get 10 or more a day, often all in one go. I don't know where these Spam are coming from, but I would like them to stop.
I also get a few emails that I would like to go straight to my inbox, going straight to the bin - for example Costa coffee, Apple News, Starbucks, PDSA, Cole & Marmalade, Cats and Kittens, GBK.  I would like these in my inbox.
I am getting so fed up with gmail, that if it wasn't such a huge pain to change to another email provider (so many accounts I would have to update), I would've changed by now.

Answer (score 2):

If the spam goes directly to bin (trash) it's not necessary to report it as Spam, instead, if you want, you could delete them immediately or left those messages there to be automatically deleted after 30 days.

It's very likely that you have a filter that are moving those messages directly to the bin (trash) that it's catching some messages that you want to keep. You could edit that filter to refine it's criteria or try to create another filter to say to Google that does messages never should be sent to the bin (trash) / marked as spam.

Related

- [Can you create rules in Gmail?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/23839/88163)
- [How to stop important emails in Gmail from going into Trash?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/69634/88163)
- [Too many good emails are designated as spam in Gmail](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/72611/88163)
- [What can cause a message to be moved to Trash in Gmail?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/101550/88163)